# Android: Eclipse build target empty, returns error and crash eclipse

Tags: android, sdk

I was running Android development on Eclipse fine for couple of months now.

But after the Android SDK update, I cannot add library to the project anymore. It just return the following screen. The Project Build Target is completly blank as shown. I COULD add the library but as soon as I hit OK, it would crash Eclipse (Eclipse becomes unresponsive, I have to end task manually)

I tried updating ADT, Android SDK and the problem persists.

Reinstall ADT doesn't help either.

As you can see in the second screen shot, Android SDK is still functional.

If anyone could help me out, I would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

[image: Adding library]
[image: System Android preferences]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling and reinstalling android related components piece by piece. I found out the The problem is with newly update (corrupted Android API 19) which caused the SDK failed to load and display properly in Eclipse.

I removed the API 19 and redownload it from Google and everything works as expected now.

Thank you.